# Eelectric and magnetic field inside a conductor cavity

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

Assume we have an external field outside a conductor that has cavity inside. I know that **E** field is 0 inside that cavity for electrostatic and time varying case but I dont understand what happens to the magnetic field **B** inside the cavity. Shouldn't it also be 0 at all times?

Answer (score 1):

Not for static magnetic field, because the mechanism that shields insides from electric field does not work for magnetic field.

External electrostatic field does not change field inside the cavity (which is zero) because conductor around the cavity forms a closed surface, and field in the conductor vanishes in equilibrium (otherwise there would be current and that would not be equilibrium state), and by the Gauss law and the fact charge density vanishes throughout the insides, the field inside the cavity necessarily has to be zero as well. The mechanism is that charges in the conductor redistribute to cancel the external field inside.

There is no law that would say that in equilibrium in ordinary conductor magnetic field has to vanish. So in general it doesn't, and thus inside the cavity it doesn't. To cancel out the external magnetic field, the conductor would have to produce its own magnetic field that would oppose the external field. Most materials in usual circumstances can't do that. Except superconductors - then total magnetic field is expelled from insides (the Meissner-Ochsenfeld effect), but that is a phenomenon that happens only for superconductors at low enough temperatures.